# How to parse multiple div with same class name in a div in cheerio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have "n" number of classes with className: "classparent"
In which I have "n" number of classes with className: "class1"
which consists of "n" number of div's with className: "class2"

How can I parse each and every of these div.class2 and get their style property in cheerio ???

Currently I am doing this :

```
$(".classParent").each((i, el) => {
    prop[i] = $(el).find(".class1 .class2").attr("style")
})
```

It returns me only one div.class2 from every .class1.

I want results like this:

```
[
 {}, // 1st object which contains all style properties of .class2 of 1st .class1
 {}, // 2nd object which contains all style properties of .class2 of 2nd .class1
 {}, // 3rd object which contains all style properties of .class2 of 3rd .class1
 ...
]
```

And this is how my objects would look like:

```
{
 "style attribute value",
 "style attribute value",
 "style attribute value",
 ......
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toArray` function:

```
$(".classParent").each((i, el) => {
    prop[i] = $(el)
        .find(".class1 .class2")
        .toArray()
        .map($)
        .map(d => d.attr("style"));
}
```

Comment: Wow man you solved my 2 days long problem!!!!

Comment: @Jimmy glad to be of help. Happy coding!